# XPS viewer for linux?

Tags: linux, xps, xps-viewer

I am using a computer with Linux.

How can I view files with the XPS extension?

Comment: @Oliver Salzburg how is "Is there an XPS viewer for linux?" "not constructive"?

Comment: @C.W.HolemanII: no, actually its a software req - these used to be alright, but eventually we decided it was just another product req. The right way to ask these questions would be in the form of a solution to a problem. See well [most of these](http://meta.superuser.com/search?q=software) for more details - its been discussed to death.

Comment: I'd like to add that – even if the question became "How can I view XPS files on Linux?" – we require a minimum amount of research effort. Even [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_XML_Paper_Specification) lists a couple of Linux programs, so unless there's any *problem* someone's facing with any of those tools, the question would be too basic.

Comment: @slhck: this was asked in 2010... (now there's plenty, back in 2010, not really). I can see why you would want to close it anyway for consistency, just saying that back in 2010, this would've been a good question :)

Comment: I know… in 2010 everything was different around here (and of course also in the world of XPS viewers), it's just that we need to find some sort of middle ground in these situations, which is a little hard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The developers of Ghostscript, Artifex, have an [XPS Viewer](http://www.artifex.com/indexxps.htm) for Linux which presumably has the same requirements as Ghostscript. The download page for the whole suite is [here](http://www.artifex.com/downloads/). Also, [here is a page from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/xps/showcase.mspx) that lists XPS related products.

Comment: Maybe that MS link used to be helpful, but now it goes to an FAQ page that only lists Windows software - not helpful at all for this question.

Comment: @JasonAntman: The [Third-party support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_XML_Paper_Specification#Third-party_support) section of the Wikipedia article on XPS should provide a partial replacement for the former content of that MS page. Additional information can be found [here](http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/xps).

Answer (score 5):

I think you should get [Okular](http://okular.kde.org/), since it's the best XPS viewer for Linux:

> Okular is a universal document viewer based on KPDF for KDE 4. This
>   means Okular works on multiple platforms, including but not limited to
>   Linux, Windows, Mac OS X, *BSD, etc.
>
> Okular combines the excellent functionalities of KPDF with the
>   versatility of supporting different kind of documents, like PDF,
>   Postscript, DjVu, CHM, XPS, ePub and others.

Comment: AFAIK, it depends on KDE.

Comment: Okular tends to corrupt characters. I read that it corrupts the national characters other than en-US, but I just used it with an entirely en-US ducument and everything but the first couple of lines were corrupt.

Comment: okular fails on my oxps file

Answer (score 3):

[mupdf](http://www.mupdf.com) is a very lightweight, fast and small PDF and **XPS** viewer.

Comment: Works great for me for XPS files that Evince can not open.

Comment: @ericzma Evince can open XPS files when gxps is installed. On Debian-based systems, you can install it via sudo apt-get install libgxps2.

Answer (score 1):

As part of the Ghostscript-related suite of `GhostPDL` page description languages, there is the commandline `gxps` which can...

- ...make XPS files display on screen: `gxps file.xps`,
- ...convert XPS files to PDF (or PostScript, JPEG, TIFF, PNG, ...).

The command to convert an XPS to PDF would be

```
gxps \
  -o output.pdf \
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
   input.xps
```